# Mongoose document after pushing it to parent document refs array is not populated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I got something like this:

```
let fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bars: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Bar' }],
});
```

and

```
let barSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sth1: String,
    sth2: String,
    sth3: String,
});
```

Both schemas are in separate files and exported as mongoose models.

So I have one `foo` document with empty `bars` array and one `bar` document, for example:

```
let foo = new Foo({ bars: [] });
let bar = new Bar({ sth1: "1", sth2: "2", sth3: "3" });
```

Then when I push `bar` into `foo`s `bars` and console log this array I got:

```
foo.bars.push(bar);
console.log(foo.bars);
//it outputs:
["59760dcbe3a7e31c2693ce47"]
```

So the `foo.bars` has only ids. 
What should I do to have whole documents in this array (without saving and then finding and populating this field)?

What I want to achieve is:

```
foo.bars.push(bar);
console.log(foo.bars);
[{ _id: 59760dcbe3a7e31c2693ce47, sth1: "1", sth2: "2", sth3: "3" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using population, but it sounds like you want to use [sub documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

```
let barSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sth1: String,
    sth2: String,
    sth3: String,
});

let fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bars: [ barSchema ]
});
```

Since there's no associated model for `barSchema`, you can't instantiate `bar` documents. You can use something like this:

```
let foo = new Foo({ bars: [ { sth1: "1", sth2: "2", sth3: "3" } ] });
```

Or:

```
let foo = new Foo;
foo.bars.create({ sth1: "1", sth2: "2", sth3: "3" });
```